# Example 1.1B, Linear Algebra - Strang

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The image below is example $1.1$ B from Strang's *Linear Algebra*

[image: quo]

I was wondering that if whole numbers do not include negative integers, then in $(1)$ why is $(-2,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ included? Also, why the 'vectors' $cv = (c,0)$ must be represented as equally spaced 'points' and not as the conventional tail-head vector representation (as shown below)? Because if we change the vector representation from point to arrow then the answer to $(1')$ may change...(I think it may..maybe I should think some other way..)

[image: cp]

Thank you in advance.........

Comment: There's not quite a consensus about the meaning of "whole numbers".  Some people (such as Strang in this example) include negative integers as "whole numbers".

Comment: One can think of a vector as either an arrow or the point at the head of that arrow when its tail is at the origin.  The math works the same either way.  If you think of them as arrows, then you'd have arrows pointing to every point of each of the lines indicated.  Typically we think of vectors as arrows when we really care about the direction (like when adding vectors or discussing tangent spaces) and we think of vectors as points when we really only care about position.

Comment: In the solution to (1), I think it would be more clear if it said, "The points $cv = (c,0)$ with whole numbers $c$ are equally spaced along the $x$-axis..."

Comment: @Bye_World: If we consider vectors as arrows then the simplest linear combination of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ will be at angle $\pi/4$ from positive x-axis and not vertical line. We can move vectors in a plane (or space) without affecting its magnitude or direction. It seems that in $(1')$, they are only considering magnitude of $(1,0)$ and not its direction. But then $(1,0)$ is a vector......

Comment: @Ritu Consider $c=2$.  Draw a couple of arrow vectors that satisfy the equation $\vec r(d) = 2\vec v + d\vec w = (2,d)$.  Obviously there are an infinite number, but just draw a few and see if you can tell that -- when the arrow vectors are draw with their tails at the origin -- the heads of every vector $\vec r(d)$ satisfying the above will be on a vertical line.  This is what we mean when we say the vector equation $\vec r(t) =\vec vt + \vec b$ is the equation of a line in $\Bbb R^n$.